# Remove element of arraylist from user input without using iteratior

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to remove any element of ArrayList, from user input and without using java iterator:

(see (switch) case 2:)

when I select Option 2 and proceed to input a name, for example James, it wont do anything as the list of friends would be the same. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FriendsTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // objects
      ArrayList<Friends> friendsList = new ArrayList<>();

      Friends a1 = new Friends("James", 10);
      Friends a2 = new Friends("Christopher", 17);
      Friends a3 = new Friends("George", 25);
      Friends a4 = new Friends("Linda", 31);
      Friends a5 = new Friends("Karen", 62);

      friendsList.add(a1);
      friendsList.add(a2);
      friendsList.add(a3);
      friendsList.add(a4);
      friendsList.add(a5);

      // menu

      int menu_choice;

      String name;
      int age;

      do
      {
         System.out.println("\n1. Add a Friend");
         System.out.println("2. Remove a Friend");
         System.out.println("3. Display all Friends");
         System.out.println("4. Exit\n");

         System.out.print("\nSelect one option: ");
         menu_choice = input.nextInt();

         switch (menu_choice)
         {
            case 1:
               System.out.print("Enter Friend's name: ");
               name = input.next();

               System.out.print("Enter Friend's age: ");
               age = input.nextInt();

               Friends a6 = new Friends(name, age);
               friendsList.add(a6);
               break;

            case 2:
               System.out.print("Enter Friend's name to remove: ");
               name = input.next();

               friendsList.remove(name);
               break;

            case 3:
               for(int k = 0; k < friendsList.size(); k++)
               {
                  System.out.println(friendsList.get(k).name + " " + friendsList.get(k).age);
               }
               break;

            case 4:
               System.exit(0);

         }//end switch        



      } while (menu_choice != 4);


   }//end main



}//end class
```

Update with my constructor and methods class

```
public class Friends 
   {
      public String name;
      public int age;

      // parameters
      public Friends(String _name, int _age)
      {
         name = _name;
         age = _age;
      }

       // set name
       public void setName(String friendName)
       {
          name = friendName;
       }

       // get name
       public String getName()
       {
          return name;
       }

       // set age
       public void setAge(int friendAge)
       {
          age = friendAge;
       }

       // get age
       public int getAge()
       {
          return age;
       }

       // return toString()
       public String toString()
       {
       return getName() + " " + getAge();
       }

    } //end clas
```

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to remove a string from an ArrayList of objects that are very much not strings. You'll need to identify which item has the name entered. Why can't you use an iterator?

Comment: Your `Friends` will need to override (and correctly implement) the `equals` and `hashcode` methods.  You should then be able to use `ArrayList#remove(T)` to remove and element by creating a new `Friends` object with the EXACT same properties as the one you have in you `List`

Comment: I might be off but how did case 2 even compile? You're trying to remove a `String` from an `ArrayList` of `Friends`.

Comment: Yeah, its a homework so we "haven't" yet seem iterators in java, is part of the specification of the homework...

Comment: @Jsch Have you seen a loop? Because essentially ANY answer will use a form of iteration within it's own implementation

Comment: Yeah It seems another way was to create a for-loop for case 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple problem: instead of passing a Friends Object to the remove() method, you pass just the String. Write a custom remove code.

Also keep in mind to always do indexed deleting from bottom to top to not jump entries:

```
            System.out.print("Enter Friend's name to remove: ");
            name = input.next();

            //                  friendsList.remove(name);
            System.out.println("Trying to locate <" + name + ">");
            for (int i = friendsList.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                final Friends f = friendsList.get(i);
                System.out.println("\tChecking with <" + friendsList.get(i).name + ">");
                if (f.name.equals(name)) {
                    System.out.println("Found that bitch at index " + i);
                    friendsList.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("... and kicked him out");
                }
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple mechanism to use is `removeIf`. Something like:

```
friendsList.removeIf(friend -> friend.hasName(name);
```

Note this uses Java 8.

That is assuming a `hasName` method of `Friend`. If you only have `getName` then:

```
friendsList.removeIf(friend -> friend.getName().equals(name));
```

Comment: Yes, I'm very new in java. But how do you apply ("whatevernamehere") dynamically so the user is the one who selects which friend to remove. I don't quite understand well, thanks!

Comment: I'll update my main post with my second class (constructor and methods)